# inserting new line with OpenOffice::OODoc

Tags: perl

I am having quite the issue creating a new line with this module and feel like I am just missing something.

my perl code looks like this:

```
use OpenOffice::OODoc;

my $name = "foo <br> bar";
   $name=~s/<br>/\n/g;

my    $outdir = "template.odt";

    my $doc = ooDocument(file => $outdir);

    my @pars = $doc->getParagraphList();
    for my $p (@pars)
    {
        $doc->substituteText($p,'{TODAY}',$date);
        $doc->substituteText($p,'{NAME}',$name);
        ...
```

Problem is when I open it in word or open office I have no newlines. Although if it open it in a text edit I have my new lines.. Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: You probably need LF + CR for your newlines. `$name =~ s/<br>/\r\n/g;`

Comment: @Cfreak just tried, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, hopefully this will save someone hours of searching for the same thing. I added:

```
use Encode qw(encode);
ooLocalEncoding('utf8');
my $linebreak = encode('utf-8', "\x{2028}");
$doc->substituteText($p,'<br>', $linebreak);
```

So my final code looks like this:

```
use OpenOffice::OODoc;
use Encode qw(encode);
ooLocalEncoding('utf8');
my $linebreak = encode('utf-8', "\x{2028}");
my    $outdir = "template.odt";

my $name = "foo <br> bar";

my    $outdir = "template.odt";

    my $doc = ooDocument(file => $outdir);

    my @pars = $doc->getParagraphList();
    for my $p (@pars)
    {
        $doc->substituteText($p,'{TODAY}',$date);
        $doc->substituteText($p,'{NAME}',$name);
        $doc->substituteText($p,'<br>', $linebreak);
        ...
```

Maybe not the best way to do things but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You could try and insert and empty para after the current one:

> If the 'text' option is empty, calling this method is the equivalent
>   of adding a line feed.

This sequence (in a text document) inserts a linefeed immediately after paragraph 4. Replace 4 with current position.

```
        $doc->insertElement
            (
            '//text:p', 4, 'text:p',
            position        => 'after',
            text            => '',
            );
```

Comment: just tried this and used $p for position and nothing seemed to change